# Вызов окна выбора пути

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

> можно ли вызвать окно выбора пути через kivy

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите эти проекты. А вообще - читайте документацию.

https://github.com/HeaTTheatR/FilechooserThumbview
https://github.com/HeaTTheatR/KivyMD/wiki/MDFileManager